# Add minutes to datetime in SQL SELECT from other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query, which selects a datetime from a database. In another column called "add_minutes" are minutes I want to add to the datetime within the query. It should look like this:

```
SELECT * from availability WHERE ? < (datetime_start + add_minutes)
```

Any hints how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer after you accepted. It now includes some performance info worth reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM availability 
WHERE ? < DATE_ADD(datetime_start, INTERVAL add_minutes MINUTE)
```

Also:

```
SELECT * 
FROM availability 
WHERE ? < ADDTIME(datetime_start, SEC_TO_TIME(add_minutes * 60))
```

Note that MySql is dumb, and both `DATE_ADD()` and `ADDTIME()` work with string expressions. Because of potential localization/formatting issues, converting between numbers and strings can be surprisingly expensive operations, especially if you have to do this for every column in a table.

Additionally, what we're doing here breaks any possibility of using indexes you might have on these columns. You can improve performance considerably like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM availability 
WHERE ADDTIME(?, SEC_TO_TIME(add_minutes * -60)) < datetime_start
```

This inverts the interval and adds it to the source value instead. It still needs to look at every value in the `add_minutes` column, regardless of index, but now `datetime_start` is unchanged, and therefore indexes on that column can still be used.

Just for fun, here's how Sql Server does it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM availability 
WHERE DATEADD(minute, add_minutes * -1, ?) < datetime_start
```

Sql Server is less dumb about it's `DATEADD()` function. Everything here is numeric; there are no messy conversions between strings and numbers or dates. Sql Server also supports computed columns with indexes. So you could include an column in the table defined as `DATEADD(minute, add_minutes, datetime_start)`, and have an index on that column. IIRC, MySql also supports computed columns, but does not support indexes on those columns.

Comment: Just to add that you can also write is as:  `? + INTERVAL add_minutes MINUTE < datetime_start` or similar